# SharePoint 2013- Using CSS to fix padding and margins after hiding Title, Logo, and Search box

Tags: css

I have used CSS to hide the Title, Logo, and Search box for the site. I would like to remove the padding so that the new site title is closer to the top. I imagine that I would need to go into SP Designer and adjust some code, I just don't know where to look.

[image]

I have had no luck in setting the margin to 0.

[image]

Comment: did you hide the title logo and search box by using `display: none`? This will hide the container too, pulling everything around it like it was never in the markup

Comment: I actually have a similar problem except I cannot do any other changes to the page because it removed the padding with the setting gear and all, so I cannot get to the editing page. Is there a way to edit the script when I cannot get to the edit mode of this particular page? It is not an access problem because I used the “display:none” code and I am the site owner. I cannot even revert back what I did, is there a way I can get the padding and setting gear back or edit the script given that I cannot click on the gear icon on this page? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those 3 elements are contained inside a `div` with id "*s4-titlerow*". Setting a `display: none;` in your CSS should do the trick.

```
#s4-titlerow {
    display: none;
}
```

Or change its `height` to zero.

```
#s4-titlerow {
    height: 0;
}
```